# GetDC() returns NULL

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, window

I have a class:

```
class Context()
{
  Context(HWND window)
  {
    m_dc = GetDC(window);
    /*...some stuff here...*/
  }

  ~Context()
  {
    ReleaseDC(m_dc);
    /*...some stuff here...*/
  }

  private:
    HDC m_dc;
}
```

The is only 1 copy of an class object during a session. This copy is created in the beggining of the session. After few (usually 5-6) session starts/stops, i have `m_dc` is `NULL` in the `ctor`. I checked that `dtor` is called as many times as ctor've been called, so i think it's always called `ReleaseDC()`. `GetLastError` doesn't change it's result after `GetDC` is called.

The question is: why do i have `NULL` as result of `GetDC`?

upd: `window` value always is not 0;

Comment: Have you checked the window handle `HWND` for each call to the ctor ?

Comment: The `GetDC` function does not set an error code, you can't use it with `GetLastError`. The documentation tells you when you can call `GetLastError`. Anyway, are you using multiple threads in the code? How are you ensuring that there's only one copy of the `Context` object "during a session"? And what do you mean by "session"? This is almost certainly a case where you're trying to call `GetDC` for a window whose device context is already "captured" by a previous call to `GetDC`. Calling `ReleaseDC` and then `GetDC` again should return non-NULL.

Comment: It would be good to see a complete program that demonstrated the fault

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: ``GetLastError`` returns 14007 before **and after** ``GetDC``. Is returns 14007 also when ``GetDC`` returns non-NULL value.

Comment: @CodyGray Ah right, totally forgot that.

Comment: @CodyGray: there are 2 threads, but the ``window`` and the ``Context`` class-object are initialized in the same thread.

Comment: Um, ReleaseDC also requires a window handle.