# On Windows Server 2019, how to I get two MFC applications to communicate using window handles and GetDC()?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have two MFC applications. The first starts up 24 instances of the other application using the below code, passing a string representation of window handle of the first window to the second.

```
void  DispatchOnTimer(HWND hwnd, UINT id)
/*************************************************************/
/*
 * Routine called every 5 seconds to see if any new images.  Only
 * spawn sub dispatchers on first call.
 */
{
  char                 TimeString[40], OldImage[_MAX_DIR], TempBuffer[81];
  int                  Count;
  long                 FileHandle;
  struct _finddata_t   FileInfo;
  STARTUPINFO          si;
  PROCESS_INFORMATION  pi;

  if (Startup)
    {

    Startup = 0;

    /* cleanup all old images */
    TextMessage(hwnd, "Searching for new images...");
    strcpy(OldImage, FAX_RECV_PATH);
    strcat(OldImage, "*.tif");
    if ((FileHandle = _findfirst(OldImage, &FileInfo)) != -1)
      {

      do
        {

        if (FileInfo.size <= MIN_TIFF_SIZE)
          {

          /* if just an 8 byte errored file delete it */
          TextMessage(hwnd, "Image found, deleting...");
          sprintf(OldImage, "%s%s", FAX_RECV_PATH, FileInfo.name);
          _unlink(OldImage);

          }

        } /* while files still found */
      while (_findnext(FileHandle, &FileInfo) != -1);

      _findclose(FileHandle);

      } /* if first file found */


    /* Winexec fax controllers */
    TextMessage(hwnd, "Initializing fax cards");
    for (Count = 0; Count < Server.TotalPorts; ++Count)
      {
        memset(TempBuffer, 0x00, 81); 
        sprintf(TempBuffer, "fax_recv -a%d -b%d -c%c -d%d -e%s",
            hwnd, Count, Server.Id, Server.Carrier, Server.Prefix);
        ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

        // 09/09/2014 - BT - Replaced "WinExec()" with "CreateProcess()".
        //if (WinExec(TempBuffer, SW_SHOW) < 32)
        if(!CreateProcess(NULL,           // Module name will be first on the command line 
                          TempBuffer,     // Command line parameters
                          NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
                          NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
                          FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                          0,              // No creation flags
                          NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
                          NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
                          &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                          &pi))           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        {
          memset(TempBuffer, 0x00, 81);
          sprintf(TempBuffer, "Error spawning line controller %d!", Count);
          MessageBox(hwnd, TempBuffer, "ERROR", MB_OK);
        }
        else // Success!
        {
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        }

      } /* loop to fire up board executables */

    } /* if first call to timer routine */

  /* Display the time in the window */
  GetFormatTime(TimeString);
  TextMessage(hwnd, TimeString);
  ErrorMessage(hwnd, "   ", 0);
  
} /* DispatchOnTimer() */
```

The second application passed messages back to the first application for the purpose of displaying to the UI using the following code:

```
void CFax_recvView::TextMessage(char acText[], int iXPosition, int iYPosition)
{
    CNewCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
    pMainWnd = CWnd::FromHandle((HWND)cmdInfo.GetMainWindow());
    CDC *dc = pMainWnd->GetDC();
    dc->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 0)); /* black */
    dc->TextOut(iXPosition, iYPosition, "                         ", 25);
    dc->TextOut(iXPosition, iYPosition, acText, strlen(acText));
    dc->DeleteDC();

} // "TextMessage()"
```

The call, `cmdInfo.GetMainWindow()`, returns the handle of the first application window to be used by the second application window.

This has worked perfectly for 20 years, but we are now migrating to Windows Server 2019 and it no longer works. The call, `pMainWnd->GetDC()` now returns `NULL`.

Does anyone know how I can get this working on Server 2019?

Comment: One small note first, the counterpart of the `GetDC()` function is `ReleaseDC()`, not `DeleteDC()`. Now, why it doesn't work on Windows Server, this is another point. First try the Win32 `::GetDC()`, just to make sure that it's not due to some MFC check. So you are trying to draw on another app's window. Maybe experiment with the flags and the security parameters. Or maybe it's a WoW feature (is your app 32-bit?), so check the application launch options. As a sidenote, this question should better have the winapi tag, not mfc or ipc (it's not legit ipc at all).

Comment: One diagnostic among many possible is to precede the GetDC by ::SetLastError(0L) to be sure and, after the (failed) call, examine what ::GetLastError returns . If the Windows Error code is Access Denied, your second application probably has a lower integrity level.

Comment: You could try `SetLastError()/GetLastError()` too, as suggested by @WilliamClements, but don't be surprised if it returns 0, most GDI functions do not set the thread's last error.

Comment: Right, sorry, I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713847/getdc-returns-null

Comment: *"This has worked perfectly"* - I doubt that's accurate. The [thread affinity rules for device contexts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051011-10/?p=33823) are subtle, and nothing in the code indicates any sort of coordination. It's not a coincidence that device contexts aren't listed under [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications). Pick one of those that doesn't read *"Clipboard"* and replace your current implementation.